# How do I get Evolution Crystals in Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Rescue Team DX?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon-dx

To evolve some pokemon species, an item called 'Evolution Crystal' is necessary. The problem is that I don't know how to get that item. I don't see it as a reward on any mission. Nor do I see it on the ground in the territories.

I have searched the internet for information but have not found anything about it. Could someone tell me how to get or find that item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to of beaten the game of in order to even find them.

Evolution Crystals are extremely difficult to find as they are considered very rare. **The best places to find them is in difficult and post-game dungeons such as Northwind Field, Silver Trench, and Joyous Tower** if you want to explore for them.

According to Serebii and Gamesradar they can also be sold in Klecon shops within dungeons as well as difficult job requests.

If there are no jobs that give them as a rewards simply take a few of the easiest jobs, complete them and then come back the next day. OR go beat a difficult dungeon and then check the jobs again the next day.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Daniel Huculak, you need to have cleared the first part of the game to unlock evolution. In post-game dungeons, evolution crystals can be found in Kecleon shops but are also guaranteed end-of-dungeon drops at the following dungeons (there may be others as well):

- Waterfall Pond (x2)
- Southern Cavern (x5)
- Buried Relic (x8)
- Marvelous Sea (x5)

Note that you don't actually need that many and since they can be found in many endgame shops, they are not particularly hard to get.

Note: Marvelous Sea and Buried Relic are not worth it if you're specifically trying to get Evolution Crystals - the former is unlocked very late and Buried Relic's drops are on the 99th floor. Southern Cavern can be incredibly challenging if you have just finished the first part of the story due to the prevalence of magnitude and earthquake by enemies and the length of the dungeon. For this reason, I recommend Waterfall Pond, though it is not a cakewalk either.